# Find the characteristic function of a random variable involving a compoud poisson distribution

Tags: probability, characteristic-function, compound-distributions

Let $\{\xi_i \}_{i=1}^{k}$ be a finite sequence of independent r.v. such that $\xi_{i} \sim F_i$.

For each $i$, let:

- $\{\xi_{i,j}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of copies of $\xi_i$, that is:  $\xi_{i,j} \sim F_i\,\,$ i.i.d.
- $N_i \sim Poisson(\lambda_i)$ be a sequence of independent poisson random variables.

Besides this, let $W$ be a **stationary** and **ergodic** **gaussian** r.v such that $W\sim F$.

So, define $Y_k$ such that:

$$Y_{k}= \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^{N_i} \xi_{i,j} $$

and $X_k$ such that

$$X_{k} = W + Y_{k} $$

I want to prove that the characterist function of $X_{k}$ is
$$\varphi_{X_k}(s)= E[e^{isX_k}]= \exp\{\lambda( E[ \exp(is\bar{\xi_k}) ]-1)\} $$
where $\lambda = (1+ \sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i)$ and $\bar{\xi_k}= \frac{1}{\lambda}(W + \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i \xi_i)$

I tryed some like this: first, writte $X_k = \sum_{i=1}^k \Big( W/k + \sum_{j=1}^{N_i} \xi_{i,j}\Big)$. Then

$$\varphi_{X_k}(s) = \Pi_{i=1}^k \varphi_{W/k}(s) \varphi_{ \sum_{j=1}^{N_i} \xi_{i,j}}(s) = \Pi_{i=1}^k \varphi_{W/k}(s) exp\{\lambda_i ( \varphi_{\xi_i}(s) -1 )  \} $$

But I can not conclude.

Some help?